# Entity Framework 6 code first multiple DbContext with multiple databases MySQL and PostgreSQL

Tags: c#, mysql, postgresql, entity-framework-6

My application has to connect to two different databases, [MySQL](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySql.Data.Entity/6.9.12) and [PostgreSQL](https://github.com/npgsql/EntityFramework6.Npgsql) database using `Entity Framework`. It works well if only one `DbContext` runs. And the second `DbContext` throws errors if the two of them run. Here's the C# code

```
[DbConfigurationType(typeof(NpgSqlConfiguration))]
public class DataContextProstreSql : DbContext
{
    public DataContextProstreSql()
        :base(ConnectionStringHelper.ConnectionStringPostgreSql)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema("public");
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }

    public DbSet<Temp> Temps { get; set; }

}

[DbConfigurationType(typeof(MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlEFConfiguration))]
//[DbConfigurationType(typeof(MySqlConfiguration))]
public class DataContextMySql : DbContext
{
    public DataContextMySql()
        : base(ConnectionStringHelper.ConnectionStringMySql)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Temp> Temps { get; set; }
}

public class NpgSqlConfiguration : DbConfiguration
{
    public NpgSqlConfiguration()
    {
        var name = "Npgsql";
        SetProviderFactory(providerInvariantName: name, providerFactory: NpgsqlFactory.Instance);
        SetProviderServices(providerInvariantName: name, provider: NpgsqlServices.Instance);
        SetDefaultConnectionFactory(connectionFactory: new NpgsqlConnectionFactory());
    }
}

public class MySqlConfiguration : DbConfiguration
{
    public MySqlConfiguration()
    {
        //var name = "MySql.Data.MySqlClient";
        SetExecutionStrategy(providerInvariantName: MySqlProviderInvariantName.ProviderName, () => new MySqlExecutionStrategy());
        SetProviderFactory(providerInvariantName: MySqlProviderInvariantName.ProviderName, providerFactory: new MySqlClientFactory());
        SetProviderServices(providerInvariantName: MySqlProviderInvariantName.ProviderName, new MySqlProviderServices());
        SetDefaultConnectionFactory(connectionFactory: new MySqlConnectionFactory());
    }
}
```

It's a desktop application and the App.Config is configured as follows

```
  <entityFramework>
    <providers>
    <provider invariantName="Npgsql" type="Npgsql.NpgsqlServices, EntityFramework6.Npgsql" />
    <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6, Version=6.9.12.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d"></provider></providers>
  </entityFramework>
<system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <remove invariant="Npgsql" />
      <add name="Npgsql Provider" invariant="Npgsql" description=".NET Framework Data Provider for PostgreSQL" type="Npgsql.NpgsqlFactory, Npgsql, Version=4.1.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5d8b90d52f46fda7" support="FF" />
      <remove invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
      <add name="MySQL Data Provider" invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for MySQL" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, MySql.Data, Version=6.9.12.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" /></DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
```

And the connection string is not stored in the App.Config file.

The exception thrown is in the second `DbContext` instance. And the error shows the first DbContext instance where it runs well. For example:

```
using (var context = new DataContextMySql()) { .... } // this works
using (var context = new DataContextProstreSql()) { .... } // <= this is MySQL error: Keyword not supported. Parameter name: entityadmindatabase


using (var context = new DataContextProstreSql()) { .... } // this works
using (var context = new DataContextMySql()) { .... } // <= this is PostgreSQL error: NpgsqlException: Unknown message code: 89
```

If I use connection string in App.Config as shown below then all the issues disappear, no more errors. Unfortunately, I have to store the connection string in json file

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="mysql" connectionString="Server=myserver.com;Port=3306;Uid=root;Pwd=secret;Database=test_db" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"/>
    <add name="postgresql" connectionString="Server=mypostgreserver.com;Port=5432;User Id=myid;Password=secret;Database=test_db;EntityAdminDatabase=test_db;Timeout=5" providerName="Npgsql"/>
  </connectionStrings>
```

Comment: Are you using the same object for the query? like from outside the context

Comment: No, I don't. Only from the context